# Windows file copying is denied although user is granted full access

Tags: windows-10, permissions, icacls

I'm trying to copy a file to another location. Because the destination folder was not originally owned by me, after searching "how to grant full access of file or folder to user on Windows", I executed the following commands to take ownership and grant myself full access:

```
takeown /F SomeFolder /R
icacls SomeFolder /grant User:(CI)(OI)F /t
```

I can confirm through Windows Explorer that I now have full access.
However, when copying, access is still denied! Windows explorer refuses to let me copy the file, and the `copy` command errors out with `Access is Denied.`

Can anyone tell me what could be happening here? Is it a permission bug? Or is there another layer of security on the folder that I can't override with `takeown` and `icacls`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Is it a permission bug?" - It is not a permission bug

Comment: Is the source file being actively used by a program?

Comment: @kicken No, it's not. Otherwise, I would have received an "In use" error.